# AsyncStorage with useContext react native: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection-Warning

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, use-context

I am trying to save useContext value with AsyncStorage and fetch the data when the app opens.

This is my code in app.js:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import ActivateContext from "./store/activate-context";

const activateReducer = (ActiveState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "ADD_ONE_POINT") {
    return ActiveState + 1;
  }
};

export default function App() {

/* Async Storage */

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("activateKEY", `${ActiveState}`);
  }, [ActiveState]);

    useEffect(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem("activateKEY").then((ActiveState) => {
        if (ActiveState) {
          activeDispatch(parseInt(ActiveState));
        }
      });
    }, []);

  const [ActiveState, dispatch] = useReducer(activateReducer, 0);

    <ActivateContext.Provider
      value={{ activeStatus: ActiveState, activeDispatch: dispatch }}>
    <Navigation />
    </ActivateContext.Provider>
```

Sadly, this does not work. I also get a warning "possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:1).

I changed it to

```
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("activateKEY", `${ActiveState}`);
  }, [ActiveState]);

useEffect(() => {       
async function getData() {
     const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem("activateKEY")
         if (key) {
           // do something after await
         }
         console.log(key)
}

//call the function
getData()


},[])
```

But it is still not working. Console.log outputs 0.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to wrap your async call in useEffect with a function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it did not work :-(

`useEffect(() => {
      function getData () {AsyncStorage.getItem("activateKEY").then((ActiveState) => {
        if (ActiveState) {
          activeDispatch(parseInt(ActiveState));
        }
      });
    }}, []);`

Answer (score 0):

The function in the useEffect hook isn't called. You also can declare the function outside the useEffect if you need to reuse it in other places.

**Edit: If there is an async call in useEffect, remember to wrap it as an async function and then call it.**

Your code should be like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
async function setData() {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem("activateKEY", `${ActiveState}`);
}

setData()
  }, [ActiveState]);
```

```js
useEffect(() => {       
async function getData() {
     const key = await AsyncStorage.getItem("activateKEY")
         if (key) {
           // do something after await
         }
         console.log(key)
}

//call the function
getData()

},[])
```

Comment: Thank you very much forbyour reply. I used your code sample bit it still wont work :-(

Comment: Do you still have the same error? Would you mind sharing your new code?

Comment: I did not change anything - I just switched my code to fetch the data with your code to fetch the data 1:1.

Comment: hello, could you successfully do a console.log(key)? what does it return?

Comment: Hey - thank you so much for your efforts! console.log(key) outputs "0". I also edited the question to show the current code setup.

Comment: Answer is updated, I think I made it unclear about the async call.

Comment: thanks again mate! Where you added the comment //do something after await I added `activeDispatch(parseInt(ActiveState));` but that gives me that error again: "possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:1)." DId I miss something?

Comment: Then the issue is possible from activeDispatch. Break down the code in detail and check to identify the issue.